# Is it safe to rename remotes in git?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have 2 remotes - origin and remote2 one and I want to rename remote2 to origin and origin to source. Is it safe to do so? If yes, how do I do it?

Edit: By safe I mean that if some branch is tracked from "origin", will it continue to be track from "source" after rename. Also I wish I new what else could go wrong :)

Comment: Define 'safe'. I can't think of any way it would break things but it's good to be specific

Comment: @Daenyth, please see my edit. I think my concern is tracking source of branches, but I might miss something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is safe, yes, unless you have scripts referencing the remote by name for instance (in which case these will still use the old remote name).

The command is:

```
git remote rename <old> <new>
```

So if you have something tracked from `foo`, then rename `foo` to `bar`, it will now be tracked from `bar`. To check, use:

```
git remote -v show
git branch -a -v
```

before and after.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, could you please also address my concern with tracking remote branches? :)

Answer (score 0):

> Also I wish I new what else could go wrong.

Not exactly "wrong", but if your remote has a log of branch/tag to update, a remote rename can be slow.

That is why, with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git remote rename A B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/47c52b2dada2d7223cfc8927ae7909dba27579a2/Documentation/git-remote.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))</sup> has been taught to show progress bar while making the user wait.

See [commit 56710a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56710a7ae0170404d7bc6411bd5c9a18124c0629), [commit c6dddb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6dddb34b57d85cc57f2efae98aed2b2539e7acd) (03 Mar 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 47c52b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47c52b2dada2d7223cfc8927ae7909dba27579a2), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/remote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56710a7ae0170404d7bc6411bd5c9a18124c0629): show progress when renaming remote references
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When renaming a remote, Git needs to rename all remote tracking references to the remote's new name (e.g., renaming "`refs/remotes/old/foo`" to "`refs/remotes/new/foo`" when renaming a remote from "`old`" to "`new`").
>
> This can be somewhat slow when there are many references to rename, since each rename is done in a separate call to `rename_ref()` as opposed to grouping all renames together into the same transaction.
>
> It would be nice to execute all renames as a single transaction, but there is a snag: the reference transaction backend doesn't support renames during a transaction (only individually, via `rename_ref()`).
>
> The reasons there are described in more detail in [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/572367B4.4050207@alum.mit.edu/), but the main problem is that in order to preserve the existing reflog, it must be moved while holding both locks (i.e., on "`oldname`" and "`newname`"), and the ref transaction code doesn't support inserting arbitrary actions into the middle of a transaction like that.
>
> `rename_ref()`'s special handling to detect **D/F (Directory/File)** conflicts would need to be rewritten for the transaction code if we wanted to proactively catch D/F F (Directory/File) conflicts when renaming a reference during a transaction.
> The reftable backend could support this much more readily because of its lack of D/F conflicts.
>
> **Instead of a more complex modification to the ref transaction code, display a progress meter when running verbosely in order to convince the user that Git is doing work while renaming a remote**.
>
> This is mostly done as-expected, with the minor caveat that we intentionally count symrefs renames twice, since renaming a symref takes place over two separate calls (one to delete the old one, and another to create the new one).

`git remote` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/56710a7ae0170404d7bc6411bd5c9a18124c0629/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L14):

> ```
> git remote rename [--[no-]progress] <old> <new>
> ```